Copy the rich text from one excel file to other excel file
Copy the cell which has rich text (E.g., black and red text combined) from one excel workbook to other excel sheet.
I am trying to do in this way but the color is not reflecting in the target file it is just plain black text but it has red colored text in between that is also seen in black with this way
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, PatternFill

def copy_cell_with_format(source_filename, source_sheet, source_cell, destination_filename, destination_sheet, destination_cell):
    # Load the source workbook
    source_workbook = load_workbook(filename=source_filename)
    source_ws = source_workbook[source_sheet]
    
    # Load the destination workbook
    dest_workbook = load_workbook(filename=destination_filename)
    dest_ws = dest_workbook[destination_sheet]
    
    # Get the source cell
    source_text = source_ws[source_cell].value
    source_font = source_ws[source_cell].font
    source_fill = source_ws[source_cell].fill
    
    # Copy text and format to destination cell
    dest_ws[destination_cell] = source_text
    dest_ws[destination_cell].font = Font(color=source_font.color)
    dest_ws[destination_cell].fill = PatternFill(start_color=source_fill.start_color.rgb, end_color=source_fill.end_color.rgb, fill_type=source_fill.fill_type)
    
    # Save the destination workbook
    dest_workbook.save(destination_filename)

# Example usage:
source_filename = "formatted_text.xlsx"
source_sheet = "Sheet1"
source_cell = "A1"

destination_filename = "y9t_mpp(auto).xlsx"
destination_sheet = "Sheet3"
destination_cell = "F1"

copy_cell_with_format(source_filename, source_sheet, source_cell, destination_filename, destination_sheet, destination_cell)



You will need to enable Rich Text for the cell data

tried but did not work.

What did you try?

TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rich_text'

What is your Openpyxl version, will need min 3.1.x. Obviously the latest release is recommended.

cmd for upgrade of openpyxl

If you are using pip:- pip install --upgrade openpyxl  Latest release is 3.1.2

But the problem is its creating new excel file but that data should append in already existinf file

It's example code, if you want to copy to an existing file then open the existing file dest_workbook = load_workbook(filename=destination_filename) instead. I'll update the code

Open the Excel file with rich_text enabled. 
Then just make the cell value in the new sheet the value from cell in the old sheet.
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def copy_cell_with_format(source_filename, source_sheet, source_cell, destination_filename, destination_sheet, destination_cell):
    # Load the source workbook
    source_workbook = load_workbook(filename=source_filename, rich_text=True)
    source_ws = source_workbook[source_sheet]
    
    # Load the destination workbook
    dest_workbook = load_workbook(filename=destination_filename)
    dest_ws = dest_workbook[destination_sheet]
    
    dest_ws[destination_cell].value = source_ws[source_cell].value  # Destination cell F1 value = Source cell A1 value
    dest_workbook.save(destination_filename)
    
# Example usage:
source_filename = "formatted_text.xlsx"
source_sheet = "Sheet1"
source_cell = "A1"

destination_filename = "y9t_mpp(auto).xlsx"
destination_sheet = "Sheet3"
destination_cell = "F1"

copy_cell_with_format(source_filename, source_sheet, source_cell, destination_filename, destination_sheet,
                      destination_cell)


TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rich_text'

Code sample updated in line with your code
